# Angular 4 form select is able to display the default value

Tags: angular, select, default, angular5, angular4-forms

```
    `<select class="form-control" id="customer" required [(ngModel)]="application.customer" name="customer" #customer="ngModel">
      <option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [ngValue]="customer">
        {{customer.id}} {{customer.first_name}} {{customer.last_name}}</option>
    </select>`
```

application.customer and customer are both type of Customer objects.  The default value is not set when application is populated in the component.  Other text input field like application.vehicle_make can be loaded without any issue.  Does anyone has any idea why default value from application isn't selected?  I am using the latest angular 5.

Answer (score 1):

Bind it with Id of your particular one use!

`<select class="form-control" id="customer" required [(ngModel)]="application.customer" name="customer" #customer="ngModel">
      <option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id">
        {{customer.id}} {{customer.first_name}} {{customer.last_name}}</option>
</select>`

Now [ngValue] trun to [value]

Answer (score 0):

There most likely isn't a `customer of customers` that equals `application.customer`. If you want a default selected you need to add that attribute to one of the items:

```
  <option *ngFor="let customer of customers; let first = first;" [ngValue]="customer" selected="first">
    {{customer.id}} {{customer.first_name}} {{customer.last_name}}</option>
```

This will select the first item in the array of `customers`. You can also use `let i = index;` in the `*ngFor` to select a certain index, or even use `let last = last`. This will set `application.customer` equal to the selected `customer of customers`.